# Swift: Finding size of element programatically on different devices

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, mkmapview, cgrectmake

For my job I am helping to design an iOS app and so I recently started working with Swift. In the app we have three different elements: a Google maps element and two graphs. I want to make it so that if you press on any of these elements they will resize to fit the screen and when you press the screen again they will go back to their original size.

Filling the screen is no problem and I already have successfully gotten that implemented. However, when you press again the element appears smaller or larger than it originally was, depending on what device you run it on. Currently I'm minimizing it by using the height and width attributes of the element and just setting them back to the original values for these attributes when the user presses the full screen element. However, it seems that these are hard coded in rather than being dynamically created for whatever device you are on and this is the reason why it won't correctly go back to it's original size.

Here is currently what I have in my code:

```
@IBAction func mapButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    if mapExpanded == false {
        mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        mapButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        mapExpanded = true
    } else {
        mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, oldMapWidth, oldMapHeight)
        mapButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, oldMapWidth, oldMapHeight)
        mapExpanded = false
    }
}
```

where oldMapWidth = self.view.mapView.width and oldMapHeight = self.view.mapView.height.

I have tried to resize it relative to the screen but that only works on a single device and gives the same issues when switching to a different tablet. Is there a different attribute that will provide the height and width after compilation so that it will be correct for the current device it is on?

Comment: Are you sure the oldMapHeight and width are what you expect them to be?  Create a log event when you press the mapButton for the first time and log the current view's width and height and compare that to what you have stored in those two variables.  I'm guessing they will be different...  The easiest solution would be to set those two variables inside the mapButtonClick just before you make it full screen.  Then returning should work just fine, no matter what device.

Comment: They were not what I thought they would be. They are equal to their size in the Any view on the storyboard which are not what they are actually on the devices when you run it. Question has been answered though, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: The question was answered 17 minutes AFTER I commented and gave you advice (which the answerer seems to have taken pretty much verbatim).

Comment: I'm sorry I guess. Obviously you were both correct, he just provided an example of doing so. If you had hit answer instead of comment, you would have been the one who got the accepted instead. Didn't really realize your solutions were basically the same until I saw this, but yes, it's the difference between an example and an tip. I promise I'm not going out of my way to actively dismiss/offend you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about preserving the frame, and setting it before expanding?  This test code seems to work perfectly for me:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapButton: UIButton!
    var mapExpanded = false
    var oldFrame = CGRectZero

    @IBAction func mapButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        if mapExpanded == false {
            // before expanding, set old
            oldFrame = mapView.frame

            mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
            mapButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
            mapExpanded = true
        } else {
            mapView.frame = oldFrame
            mapButton.frame = oldFrame
            mapExpanded = false
        }
    }
}
```

In my example I am using AutoLayout in the Storyboard to place the map and button.  I recommend doing the same.

Comment: That's really slick. I didn't know you could just do something as simple as just setting one frame equal to another. Looks like this works perfectly. Thanks for the help!